Flutter [camera_android] change LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE for Android Device
I’m using Flutter's camera plugin but need more control over native camera settings like:

Adjusting manual focus distance (LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE)
Enabling/disabling image stabilization (LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE)
Switching between camera lenses (wide-angle, telephoto)

The camera plugin doesn't expose these controls, but I need to modify them for both Android (Camera2 API) and iOS (AVFoundation). I've successfully implemented these changes on iOS, but I’m stuck on Android because the plugin creates its own CaptureRequest instance, which I can't access.
iOS
device.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: distance) { (time) in
  device.unlockForConfiguration()
}

Android
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, distance);

I’m stuck on Android because the plugin creates its own CaptureRequest instance, which I can't access.
Has anyone worked on a similar solution or found a workaround for this?

Related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111476 so unless you want to write your own native connection you may want to look for a third-party package that supports your needs: https://pub.dev/packages?q=camera (software recommendations are off-topic here)
